# UI controls not reflecting model change if property is updated too quickly

Tags: angular

I suspect I'm doing something naughty here but it's unclear to me how one should handle this scenario.

I have a select control with various options.  When a user selects an option I am performing a check to determine if that value is in an acceptable range and if NOT I am forcing the value to a minimum value that is acceptable.

What's happening is the select control acts wonky.  Sometimes it will update to show the new bound value whereas other times it just shows what was selected (despite the underlying model having the expected value).  However, if I wrap the check and property setting in a setTimeout() function it will behave as expected.

I have tried injecting changeDetectorRef and calling detectChanges after setting the value but this doesn't work either.

Example code demonstrating the problem:

```
    @Component({
        selector: 'my-app',
        template: `
    <form #form="ngForm">

        <div>
        <label>Select
            <select
            name="select"
            [(ngModel)]="selected"
            (ngModelChange)="onSelectChange()">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
            </label>
        </div>
    <br/>
    <div>
        <label>Delayed Select
            <select
            name="delayedSelect"
            [(ngModel)]="delayedSelected"
            (ngModelChange)="onDelayedSelectChange()">
                <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                <option value="3">Option 3</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </div>
    </form>
        `,
    })
    export class App {
        selected: string;
        delayedSelected: string;

        constructor() {    
        }

        onSelectChange():void {
            // nope! can't select 3, 2 is the highest you can go!
            if (this.selected === '3'){
                this.selected = '2';
            }
        }

        onDelayedSelectChange():void {
            setTimeout(()=>{
            // nope! can't select 3, 2 is the highest you can go!
            if (this.delayedSelected === '3'){
                this.delayedSelected = '2';
            }},0);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't implement a custom validator to make sure the value is within a certain range you deem acceptable?

Comment: I realize there are alternate approaches to this problem, but this is the design the client wants.  Also I want to understand what I'm doing wrong as other scenarios might require something similar.

Comment: Does using `(change)` rather than `(ngModelChange)` in the template work?

Comment: Same deal with (change).

Comment: Try your setTimeout with 0ms and see if it still works, because it forces change detection it will let you know if its a change detection problem (which it probably is). If it is you just need to find where to run detectChanges(). If not at least you will have narrowed down your problem.

Comment: Setting it to 0ms does indeed cause it to update properly. But where would I possibly run detectChanges instead? Calling it after changing the property value is the most logical place and that doesn't work --I would have to wrap THAT in a setTimeout.

Comment: I would like to add that using Reactive forms technique does not experience this problem.